# Hot get rich text of cells in Numbers

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks, iwork, apple-numbers

I want to convert rich text cell content of my numbers table to other formats like Markdown or HTML. But how do I get more then just plain text?

Maybe there's a solution how to set the selection range and copy it as rtf to the clipboard.

```applescript
tell application "Numbers"
    get formatted value of cell 2 of row 2 of table 1 of sheet 1 of document of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Select the cell and then invoke copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script to select the cell and then copy the contents to the clipboard which preserves the formatting:

```applescript
tell application "Numbers"
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document of window 1
        activate
        set selection range to cell 2 of row "2" --range "B2:B2"
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Numbers"
            keystroke "c" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```